Output dataset in Javascript without quotemarks
I have a simple script to output data from my HTML, but the output is in quotes i.e. "10". How do I get it to return just the number i.e. 10
https://codepen.io/Ruth-Vant/pen/KKjJRMN?editors=1111
<div id="zoomsize" data-myattribute="10" value="10" >10</div>
const div = document.getElementById("zoomsize");
console.log(div.dataset.myattribute);

It's because you're dealing with a string. Convert it to a number to remove the quotes

I get NaN, even though it is obviously 10

This works
const div = document.getElementById("zoomsize");
var x = (div.dataset.myattribute);
console.log(x*1);
